# Making custom ArcMap toolbar part of default document

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, toolbar, customize-mode

At ArcMap 10.7.1, I have created this custom toolbar, which contains a single tool:

[image]

I need that toolbar to "stick", so that it always appears when I open a new or existing map document (I think that means my new toolbar becomes part of Normal.mxt?).

However, this toolbar does not appear when I subsequently open a map document.  According to [this ArcGIS help document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00v000000005000000), I need to have Customize > Customize Mode > Options > "Save all customizations to the document" checked ***off***, as shown here:

[image]

However, I am unable to get it to "stick", no matter what combination of boxes I check and uncheck; the custom toolbar does not appear when I open a map document.

This issue was brought up at [Custom Tools not Saving in Toolbar on Startup/ Normal.mxt?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88647) over three years ago in 10.1.  Is it still true that you cannot make a custom toolbar part of the ArcMap default view?

Here's a quote from [the 10.7 Help page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/get-started/customizing-the-ui/creating-a-new-toolbar.htm) (my emphasis):

*When you create a custom toolbar—in ArcMap, for example—it will save with the current map document by default. **If you want to save a toolbar in the Normal template so that all documents see it, uncheck the Create new toolbars and menus in document check box** on the Options tab on the Customize dialog box.*

Comment: If you are wanting to ask the same question, just at a later version, then I think you should write an answer to that question which says that you have been able to reproduce it at your specified version, and describing the precise steps that you use to reproduce it.

Comment: What is the purpose? Geoprocessing using new mxd?

Comment: Geoprocessing for a small organization, always available as a toolbar.